# Issue with displaying label for the discrete legends after using view box attribute for svg

Tags: svg, label, legend, discrete

I have created the discrete legend using svg and I want to show the index as its label.

```
// creating svg
selectedLegend
.append("svg")
.attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${count} 1`)
.attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none")

function legend(g: any) {
// appending data
g.selectAll("g.legendCells")
.data(itemColor)
.enter()
.append("rect");
// appending text for label, which is not working as expected
g.selectAll("rect")
.append("text")
.attr("class", "breakLabels")
.style("fill", "red")
.attr("x", cellWidth + cellPadding)
.attr("y", 5 + cellHeight / 2)
.text(function (d: Record<string, unknown>, i: any) {
// return the index, which should be label for legend
return i;
});
}
```

Fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/03bxhoyq/2/

I want like below red it must show label as 0 and 1 for blue and so on.

Something like this but please note the image is vertical legend and mine in horizontal.

[image]

Comment: Try with a `font-size` attribute for the `<text>` element.

Comment: What will be the x and y value for the text ? Also is it an correct way to append the text to the rect ? Do I need extra attribute to svg or text as font size not seems to work. Fiddle link after adding text to the rect https://jsfiddle.net/ghze6cm8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful not to place the `<text>` elements as children to `<rect>`. They are independent. The scaling (`preserveAspectRatio="none"`) also apply to the text, so it could be a good idea to have an SVG inside another SVG. The inner SVG has the scaling and the outer SVG has the texts. The outer SVG has a viewBox that matches the height/width ratio (10 to 1 is = to 250 to 25).

On the `<text>` I added the attributes  `dominant-baseline="middle"` and `text-anchor="middle"` to position the handle of the text in the middle of it.

```html
<div id="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 20 2" width="400px">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 4 1" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="1" >
      <rect x="0" y="0" height="1" width="1" style="fill: rgb(255, 46, 0);"/>
      <rect x="1" y="0" height="1" width="1" style="fill: rgb(0, 184, 0);"/>
      <rect x="2" y="0" height="1" width="1" style="fill: rgb(0, 25, 255);"/>
      <rect x="3" y="0" height="1" width="1" style="fill: rgb(179, 179, 179);"/>
    </svg>
    <g dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size=".73">
      <text x="2.5" y="1.5" style="fill: black;">0</text>
      <text x="7.5" y="1.5" style="fill: black;">1</text>
      <text x="12.5" y="1.5" style="fill: black;">2</text>
      <text x="17.5" y="1.5" style="fill: black;">3</text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But unfortunately I want text to be below the svg and not in the svg. Something like as shown above (I have updated question and attached the image). The image I shared shows vertical but mine will be still horizontal.

Comment: Currently my code look like this : https://jsfiddle.net/3mcxk49q/1/ . I assume that something going wrong with the x and y value of the text but not able to figure it out

Comment: You have a "coordinate system" (the viewBox) starting at 0,0 and ending at 4,2. All positions (x and y values) should be in that range. Look at my example above. the y value is .5 -- half the total height of 1.

Comment: Can you help me out with this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/cgue7b4L/3/ ? I have changed the x and y value but still not able to get label. Also the text should come below cells/rect (in the grey background) and not in middle of the cells/rect.

Comment: add `font-size=".5"` to `<svg>`. And alter the last text: `<text class="breakLabels" x="3.25" y="1.5" style="fill: red;">3</text>` etc. You still have the same problem with a stretched text. Solve that by using a setup like the example in my answer

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works. The mistake I was doing earlier is giving font size to the text and not for the svg.

Comment: Unfortunately my requirement is changed and text needs to be shown on hovering on the rect and not at bottom. I tried adding hover css and also mouseover event but I see mouseover act as onClick and not called while hovering. Is there any other way so that label can be shown on hovering on rect ?